# CSS :hover selector not getting triggered

Tags: html, css

Whenever I hover over the div, it doesn't trigger the :hover selector. But when I force:hover the div on Inspector, the css of the :hover gets applied. What is wrong with my code?

**HTML:**

```
<div class='subject paper'>
    <div class='subjectHeader'>Physics</div>
    <div class='subjectContent'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.subject > div.subjectHeader {


    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 200px;
    transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.2,1);

}

div.subject > div.subjectHeader:hover {
    height: 30px !important;
    line-height: 30px !important;
    font-size: 1.5em !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    padding-left: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: Is something perhaps covering it? (Bring up the context menu and Inspect Element to find out!)

Comment: There should be no need for all those `!important` declarations either. That's indicative of another issue somewhere.

Comment: When I try it, the body gets selected on the inspector. This may be an issue of z-index. The container the .subject divs has z-index of -1. I tried making the z-index of the body to -999 but still it doesn't work.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem on jsfiddle.net Probably you will get the solution urself in the process..

Comment: We would need a link to the offending website. The code you have provided works ok http://jsfiddle.net/b3AJt/

Comment: Do you have a link so we could look at it?  It would be easier to inspect that way.

Comment: @Paulie_D If I remove the !important, the :hover styles don't get applied. The styles for :hover gets masked by the other style.

Comment: It is running on localhost. I don't have an online site yet. How do you think I can provide a link to it?

Comment: I got it now. As suspected, it is an issue of z-indexing. I just re-arranged the z-indices. I provided a positive valued z-index to the container of the divs. Thanks to you guys!

Answer (score 0):

This is just an issue of z-indexing. I just provided a positive valued z-index to the container of the .subject divs. The body is over the divs hindering the hover selector not to be triggered. I re-arranged the z-indeces such that the body is under the container of the .subject divs.